# Как проверить загрузился ли элемент или нет (JavaScript)

Tags: javascript, html, css

Доброе времени суток вам все. Сделал, что-то подобие слайда. Но из-за скорости и-нета он начинает работать до полной загрузки картинки. В итоге начинают меняться незагруженные картинки. Вопрос.  Как проверить загрузилась ли картинка или нет.   Заранее огромное спасибо.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

У тега `img` есть атрибут `onload`, в котором можно указать функцию, которая выполнится, когда картинка полностью загрузится. Например, можно завести массив флагов, а на обработчик `onload` повесить что-то вроде такого:

```
<script>var loaded = Array(3);</script>

<img src="picture0.jpg" onload="loaded[0] = true;" />
<img src="picture1.jpg" onload="loaded[1] = true;" />
<img src="picture2.jpg" onload="loaded[2] = true;" />
```

Теперь вы будете знать, какие из картинок уже загрузились, а какие нет.

Comment: к сведению: В IE, когда картинка берется из кеша onload не срабатывает.

Answer (score 1):

Для того что бы корректно работало событие onload - нужно навешивать его до начала загрузки картинок. В Вашем случае проще всего поменять src для каждой картинки после того как повесите обработчик onload:

```
var $images = $('.slider img')
  , counter = 0
  ;
// Проходимся по каждой картинке и навешиваем обработчик
$images.each(function(){
    $(this).load(function(){
        counter++;
        // Если подгрузились все картинки, то инициализируем слайдер
        if($images.length===counter){start();}
    });
    // Меняем src для инициализации load
    $(this).attr('src', $(this).attr('src'));
});
```

**PS**
Тем кто писал текстовый редактор для ответов нужно оторвать руки!